# Python Selenium clicking on element doesn't work - Unable to get the file

Tags: selenium

I'm using Selenium package in Python.

```
<td align="right" valign="middle" title="">
    <a href="/modules/etat/etat.php?file=Détails DA Année en cours2021.xlsx">26/01/2021</a><br>
    <a href="/modules/etat/etat.php?file=Détails DA Année en cours2021.xlsx" title="26/01/2021">10/04/2021</a><br>
</td>
```

In normal use, clicking on the link, I get the file directly downloaded in Downloads folder (I'm using Chromedriver)
In Selenium, I select the element by partial_link_text search wihtout issue. But clicking on it doesn't do anything :( (no error)

```
elems = driver.find_elements_by_partial_link_text('Détails DA')
for elem in elems:
    elem.click()
```

I also tried to go directly to the link by driver.get() but same effect (going directly to the link in the borwser doesn't work neither).

Note that there is a js script on this page. Maybe the issue. I'm far from an expert :/

```
<script src="/js/etat/etat.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
```

Any help appreciate.
thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the first locator use xpath:

```
link1 = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[contains(text(), '26/01/2021')]")
```

For the second one use:

```
link2 = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[contains(@title,'26/01/2021')]")
```

or:

```
link2 = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[contains(text(), '10/04/2021')]")
```

Also, add explicit wait:

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, timeout=30)
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//a[contains(text(), '10/04/2021')]")))
el = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[contains(text(), '10/04/2021')]")
list_view.click()
```

Comment: Thanks. But I have an error message on selection : selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element:

Comment: Add a bigger or link to site. If you don't know how to correctly format it place as a plain text. I'll help with editing. Also, add the code you are executing

Comment: when I do print(driver.page_source), the part of html where I should find these elements are replaced by "<tr>
        <td id="pagingArea"></td>
    </tr>"

Comment: Add this to question, so I could search for locators you are looking for. The same way as you did previously: html code.

Comment: Again, not an expert at all, but can't be the js mentioned above htat is not executed properly in "selenium session"? Still strange to me because when I look to the chrome window opened by selenium, the code is there, not in the driver.page_source...

Comment: try using time.sleep(10) before finding the element, same error?

Comment: Of course it can be, but how will I know what it is without seeing page?

Comment: OK, I'll add a better solution.

Comment: Check one more thing you will have to add instead of time.sleep here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67060411/python-selenium-no-such-element-unable-to-locate-element/67060770#comment118536810_67060770 You will need to add explicit wait (and switch to iframe if the element in iframe)

Comment: Check for updated answer and accept if the issue is resolved.

Comment: New code didn't make the trick (even replacing list_view by el ;) ). no erro but no downloaded file

Comment: It works with time.sleep(2) AFTER the click()! :/

Comment: Then temporarily use time.sleep and you will need to define what elements Selenium needs to wait for.

Comment: When you learn about waits in Selenium, post a separate question, if you will still have problems with downloading other elements.

Comment: https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html read here

Comment: Yep. Already accepted the solution. thank you so much. Seems I will have to put waits on every side ;)

Answer (score 0):

Try this -

```
elems = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[contains(@href, '/modules/etat/etat.php?file=Détails DA Année en cours2021.xlsx')]").click()
```

Comment: Same error : "selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//a[contains(@href, '/modules/etat/etat.php?file=Détails DA Année en cours2021.xlsx')]"}
  (Session info: chrome=89.0.4389.114)"