# Python/Selenium - "no such element: Unable to locate element"

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, webdriverwait

I'm having a really hard time locating elements on [this website](https://www.weforum.org/reports/global-gender-gap-report-2021/in-full/economy-profiles#economy-profiles). My ultimate aim here is scrape the score card data for each country. The way I've envisioned doing that is to have selenium click list view (as opposed to the default country view) and loop going in and out of all the country profiles, scraping the data for each country along the way. But methods to locate elements on the page that worked for me in the past, have been fruitless with this site.

Here's some sample code outlining my issue.

```py
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path= "C:/work/chromedriver.exe")
driver.get('https://www.weforum.org/reports/global-gender-gap-report-2021/in-full/economy-profiles#economy-profiles')

# click the `list` view option
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="root"]/div/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/svg[2]')
```

As you can see, I've only gotten as far as step 1 of my plan. I've tried what other questions have suggested as far as adding waits, but to no avail. I see the site fully loaded in my DOM, but no xpaths are working for any element on there I can find. I apologize if this question is posted too often, but do know that any and all help is immensely appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Did you manage to click List view?

Comment: Remove Javascript tag

Comment: Removed it, thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The element is inside an iframe you need to switch it to access the element.

Use `WebDriverWait()` wait for `frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it()`

```
driver.get("https://www.weforum.org/reports/global-gender-gap-report-2021/in-full/economy-profiles#economy-profiles")
wait=WebDriverWait(driver,10)
wait.until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.ID, "iFrameResizer0")))
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"//*[name()='svg' and @class='sc-gxMtzJ bRxjeC']"))).click()
```

You need following imports.

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
```

[image]

Another update:

```
driver.get("https://www.weforum.org/reports/global-gender-gap-report-2021/in-full/economy-profiles#economy-profiles")
wait=WebDriverWait(driver,10)
wait.until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.ID, "iFrameResizer0")))
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[name()='svg' and @class='sc-gxMtzJ bRxjeC']").click()
```

Comment: This was able to click the list view! But I'm not sure how you found the iframe or how you knew to construct the xpath like that to use `and`. It seems that notation doesn't work when I try and extend it work via `driver.find_element_by_xpath()`

Comment: This answer s more full. There is really iframe and it's also the problem.

Comment: @Yacob : If you see the DOM tree you see the parent node it is an iframe.

Comment: @Yacob : Answer to your second query when you access `SVG` element you need to use following `xpath` format.

Comment: @Yacob : `driver.find_element_by_xpath()` This will work as well check my updated answer.

Comment: Okay, one last thing. How would I construct the xpath to locate the buttons for each country once in list view? It's unable to find them, and I tried using `name=div()` in in the place of  `name()='svg'` and replaced class with `'sc-dNLxif WGblC'`, but it was unable to locate the country button. **EDIT** Nevermind it worked, I was able to click the country button.

Comment: @Yacob : That is not svg element. To get the list of country name you can use following xpath : `//div[@id='root']//a[@class='sc-chPdSV lcYVwX sc-kAzzGY kraFwA']/div[1]/div`

Comment: Use `diver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@id='root']//a[@class='sc-chPdSV lcYVwX sc-kAzzGY kraFwA']/div[1]/div") ` and then use for loop to iterate and get the text value. Note : you need to wait for element to load once you click on list view.

Comment: Thank you for your time. This was the answer I needed. My only desire would be to know how you arrived at the answer you did, but for now I can at least move forward with my project.

Comment: @KunduK are you able to help me with a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67095490/elementclickinterceptedexception-message-element-click-intercepted-how-to-lo)? I hit another snag with the iframe when looping through the country links

Comment: @Yacob : Sorry just saw your message and I think you got couple of suggestion from other contributor if that doesn't work for you let know i will have a look then thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You incorrectly click List view. Your locator has to be stable. I checked it did not work.
So, in order to click the icon, use `WebDriverWait`:

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, timeout=30)
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".sc-gzOgki.ftxBlu>.background")))
list_view = driver.find_element_by_css_selector(".sc-gzOgki.ftxBlu>.background")
list_view.click()
```

Next, to get the unique row locator, use the following `css` selector:

```
.sc-jbKcbu.kynSUT
```

It will give use the list of all countries.

Comment: Unfortunately, I still receive "Unable to locate element" :(

Comment: Which element exactly?

Comment: `list_view = driver.find_element_by_css_selector(".sc-gzOgki.isBUmS>.background")`. This wasn't working for me. I'm guessing it was for you?

Comment: It's still not finding it. Did you not need to switch to an iframe? That's what worked for locating list view element as suggested by KunduK

Comment: @KunduK suggested to also to switch to iframe. He is right