# ElementClickInterceptedException: Message: element click intercepted - how to locate and switch to iframe in a for loop

Tags: python, selenium, iframe

I'm trying to to loop through 162 links of country rankings on a JavaScript page and click in and out of each country. For the first 13 or so country links they work, but once I get to around Belgium (give or take), I'm hit with `ElementClickInterceptedException: Message: element click intercepted: Element <iframe class="js-lazyload loaded" data-src="https://assets.weforum.org/static/reports/gender-gap-report-2021/v8/index.html"...`. Earlier in the script I handled an iframe, but I'm not sure what I need to know and do in order to find and switch to an iframe in this loop should an iframe arise. Here's my code:

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import re

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path= "C:/work/chromedriver.exe")

def load_list_page(returnlist = False):
    '''
    This function takes you to the list view of country rankings for the Gender Gap Index.
    There's a default option to return all country rankings on the page as a list.
    '''
    driver.get("https://www.weforum.org/reports/global-gender-gap-report-2021/in-full/economy-profiles#economy-profiles")
    
    # bring up list view of countries
    wait=WebDriverWait(driver,10)
    wait.until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.ID, "iFrameResizer0")))
    wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"//*[name()='svg' and @class='sc-gzOgki ftxBlu']"))).click()
    
    if returnlist:
        list_of_countries = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@id='root']//a[@class='sc-chPdSV lcYVwX sc-kAzzGY kraFwA']/div[1]/div")

        return list_of_countries

# Collect country names
countries = load_list_page(returnlist=True)
country_names_raw = [i.text for i in countries]
# get all non-empty strings
country_names = [i for i in country_names_raw if len(i)>0]
# extract just the country name using regex
country_names = [re.match(r'\d{,3}. ([\w\s,\'\.]+).*\n', i).group(1) for i in country_names]

# Record the index for the country names that had non-empty strings. These indexes reference WebElements that
# will link to the country profile page. Use these indices to grab the webelements that link to country profiles
# NOTE: I had to add 1 to each index since it seems the link is in the webelement immediately after the webelement with the country text 
link_index = [i+1 for i, j in enumerate(country_names_raw) if len(j) > 0]

# Loop through and click country rankings
for index, link in enumerate(link_index[:14]):
    try:
        countries = load_list_page(returnlist=True)
        countries[link].click()
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"{e}")
        print(f"Error for {country_names[index]}, link index: {link}")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for index, link in enumerate(link_index[:14]):
    try:
        countries = load_list_page(returnlist=True)
        #countries[link].click()
        driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", countries[link])
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"{e}")
        print(f"Error for {country_names[index]}, link index: {link}")
```

You can invoke click directly on the element to bypass the overlapping element.

Comment: While this didn't answer the question in the way I had posed it, it certainly got me to the end goal, and in a far simpler way.

Comment: That way is not correct. It will work correctly for several nearest elements (number 13-15 etc. in the list) that are already loaded and existing but just covered by other elements, however this will probably not work if you try clicking 100-th or 150-th elements in the list

Comment: You can use scroll to view if it's completely random as well.

Comment: 1) That's exactly what I answered
2) Even for ordered clicking on the links your solution will work for initially loaded elements only

Answer (score 1):

When iterating through the list of countries,

```
for index, link in enumerate(link_index[:14]):
```

before clicking on the element scroll that element into the view.
`Java` method performing this looks like:

```
public void scrollElementIntoView(WebElement element){
        waitForElementToBeVisible(element);
        ((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", webElement);
        wait(300);
    }
```

`Python` method will be similar.